# How to add a global variable to in setup.cfg file?

Tags: python, setuptools

I have two modules (`isort` and `pycodestyle`). I want to remove duplication and to be able to supply both with the same list of files to ignore. Is it possible to store this in some kind of constant syntax at the top of the file then reference it later? If so what is the syntax?

At the moment I have:

```
[pycodestyle]
exclude =
    foo.py,
    bar.py,
    baz.py

[isort]
skip_glob =
    foo.py,
    bar.py,
    baz.py
```

I am open to solutions using `pyproject.toml` if this isn't possible with `setup.cfg`

Comment: Do you mean `setup.py`? Because `setup.cfg` is not currently recommended, for an uncomplicated approach `pytest.ini` is currently favored. Please [notice the warning in pytest configuration options](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#configuration-options).

Comment: @bad_coder That recommendation is for `pytest`, not for generic Python. The question is not about `pytest` but about other tools.

Comment: @bad_coder thanks for the researched suggestion but as already raised I really need a general solution.

Comment: @EdwinShepherd I honestly don't know what the solution for this would be. I can get `setup.py` working for my own projects, but I don't have much expertise...A possible suggestion: see if there are more tags that may somehow refine the scope (but as I understand it, this does seem like a setuptools problem in essence.)

Comment: I would really like to know this as well